# golang javascript ui issue

Tags: jquery, go

Following html works standalone

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.del').live('click',function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

            $('.add').live('click',function(){
                $(this).val('Delete');
                $(this).attr('class','del');
                var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='name[]' /></td> <td><input type='text' name='value[]' /></td> <td><input type='checkbox' name='regex[]' /></td><td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";
                $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        table {
          table-layout: fixed;
          width:1200px;
        }
        input{
          width:285px;
        }
    </style>
 </head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="/silencealert">
    <table id="options-table">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Regex</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"   name="name[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text"   name="value[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="regex[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class='del' value='Delete' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"   name="name[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text"   name="value[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"   name="regex[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add More" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <label for="number"> Expires(Days[1-30]): </label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="30" value="" name="days">
    <br><br>
<button type="submit">SilenceAlert</button>
  </form>
    <hr>
    <small>User: %s</small>
</body>
```

With the above file when i click on Add More a new table row gets added and when i click delete a table row gets deleted. which is the expected behaiour.

I am using the above html in a golang project (file - main.go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

const manage_alertsPage = `
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.del').live('click',function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });

                $('.add').live('click',function(){
                    $(this).val('Delete');
                    $(this).attr('class','del');
                    var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='name[]' /></td> <td><input type='text' name='value[]' /></td> <td><input type='checkbox' name='regex[]' /></td><td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";
                    $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            table {
              table-layout: fixed;
              width:1200px;
            }
            input{
              width:285px;
            }
        </style>
     </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/silencealert">
        <table id="options-table">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Value</td>
                <td>Regex</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"   name="name[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="text"   name="value[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"  name="regex[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class='del' value='Delete' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"   name="name[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="text"   name="value[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"   name="regex[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add More" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <label for="number"> Expires(Days[1-30]): </label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="30" value="" name="days">
        <br><br>
    <button type="submit">SilenceAlert</button>
      </form>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
`

func manage_alertsPageHandler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(response, manage_alertsPage)
}

func silencealertPageHandler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    err := request.ParseForm()
  if err != nil {
      // Handle error here via logging and then return     
    fmt.Fprintf(response, "There was an error processing form: " + err.Error()) 
    return      
  }
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", request.Form)

    fmt.Fprintf(response, manage_alertsPage)
}

// server main method

var router = mux.NewRouter()

func main() {

  router.HandleFunc("/manage_alerts", manage_alertsPageHandler)
    router.HandleFunc("/silencealert", silencealertPageHandler)

    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

The folder structure for the go project is

```
src/web
 - main.go
 - jquery-1.7.min.js
```

when i run the go project:

```
go run main.go
```

Browse to

```
localhost:8000/manage_alerts
```

Click on Add More or Delete button, nothing happens

Need some help to figure out why javascript code is not executing here when it was executing just fine outside of the golang code.

Comment: It might not like your path for jquery. Have you checked your console for errors? You might also need to add the right Content-Type to the response headers when serving content files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the HTML file directly in the browser, the browser will look for the jquery file in your file system. When you view the page by navigating to `localhost:8000/...` the browser will look for the jquery file at `localhost:8000/...`.

---

Your Go app can handle requests to only those two paths that your registered. The html page it renders will make a request to `localhost:8000/jquery-1.7.min.js` to download the jquery file but you did not register a handler to handle such a request...

That is, you're missing something like this:

```
router.HandleFunc("/jquery-1.7.min.js", serveJQuery)
```

In the real world though you probably will want to serve more than just a single file, so have a look at `gorilla/mux`'s readme on [static files](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#static-files) for a more complete solution.